# How do I reload new column fields into iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a table  report in *iReport*.

table data is backed by SQL Query.

Now I want to modify the sql query to add 2 more columns in my report .

How do I reload new column fields into *iReport* now?  There is no 'Reload Query'  button in *iReport*.

How do I do it?

Comment: Do you mean how to add 2 more columns to the existing table or If you are talking about the query, in the query editor, it would automatically detect changes if you have enabled the 'Automatically Click Field Options' or  just click read fields. If you are talking about how to add columns to already existing table, right click on the last column select Table and there you can see the options of adding columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. open Report Query
2. click Automatically Retrieve Field
3. modify your query
4. your query is updated when there's message "Ready"
5. click ok and you're done